# AngularJS scope of controller variable depending on if it's attached to scope or this

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following controller definition:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp");

app.controller("ViewCtrl", function($scope) {
    this.panelVisible = true;

    this.panelShowHide = function() {
        this.panelVisible = !this.panelVisible;
    }
});
```

And here is my view:

```
<body ng-controller="ViewCtrl as view">
    <a href="" ng-click="view.panelShowHide()">Button</a>
    {{view.panelVisible}}
</body>
```

From my view I am calling panelShowHide function, and contrary to my expectation `this.panelVisible = !this.panelVisible` line somehow updates controller variable (defined in `this.panelVisible = true;` line)

How is that possible? I understand if I did `$scope.panelVisible`, but since I am doing `this.panelVisible` in panelShowHide function, shouldn't that line create and update new variable defined within the scope of function?

I am asking this so that I better understand the scope in AngularJS since in some more complicated cases (like using $http.get) my this.reference is "properly resolved" (to local variable) and I would prefer the be able to reference controller variables (encapsulate logic).

Comment: I could be wrong; but the panelShowHide() function is already in a function; so the 'this' refers to the top-most function.  You can remove 'this' to create a function local variable.  If you want to access the anchor; I'm not sure the best way.

Comment: @Reboog711 Yeah - after looking through links I think I cleared it up - first this appends variable to function($scope) and this.panelVisible within the inline function references parent (i.e. function($scope) function). I'm just not 100% if first this acts like that (attaches to self, rather then to natural parent - i.e. window) because of something Angular does or that's normal JS behaviour for functions defined like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the `ng-controller="ViewCtrl as view"` feature does is publish an instance of your controller on `$scope` under a property named `view`, e.g. :

[image]

Since `$scope.view` is an instance of your controller and `panelShowHide()` a function on your controller object, the 'owner' of `panelShowHide()` function is the controller instance and hence `this` points to it.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter a new function, you must always be suspicious of the value of `this`.  Try this:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp");

app.controller("ViewCtrl", function($scope) {
    var self= this;
    self.panelVisible = true;

    self.panelShowHide = function() {
        self.panelVisible = !self.panelVisible;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah - that's exactly what confuses me... in AngularJS I don't need to do self.panelVisible = !self.panelVisible - this instead of self will work completely fine in some cases for some reason.

Comment: This is a JavaScript issue, nothing to do with Angular.  `this` is the object upon which the function was invoked.  Give this a read: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html